# How do you add extra headers into request in Android GeckoView?

Tags: android, mozilla, geckoview

I found [this thread](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1567549) on the Mozilla bug tracking website. It seems like the issue [was addressed](https://hg.mozilla.org/integration/autoland/rev/dad383db9474). However, when I go to import a recent version of the library from maven in Android Studio. Specifically version `org.mozilla.geckoview:geckoview-nightly:100.0.20220308100756`.

The only method signature I am able to use is `GeckoSession.loadUri(uri)`. The desired `GeckoSession.loadUri(uri, extraHeaders)` is nowhere to be found. Anyone have any insights into this? I am afraid that the documentation is quite sparse around here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this I make use of GeckoSessions' [Loader](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/GeckoSession.Loader.html), which allows you to use a Builder-like format to pass in values.

To do this, I'd write:

```
Map <String, String> extraHeaders = Map.of("Key 1", "Value 1", "Key 2", "Value 2", etc.);

GeckoSession.Loader loader = new GeckoSession.Loader();
loader.additionalHeaders(extraHeaders);
loader.uri("https://example.com");

geckoSession.load(loader);
```

Worth noting that theoretically you shouldn't need to assign each method to the loader like this and instead use a more conventional Builder-like format, but in my experience GeckoSession seems to fail at loading in https headers when you don't have them already declared in a Map before passing, so this is easiest.

Comment: Unresolved reference: Loader